# while saving the value in asp Cookie "+" sign is coming instead of space

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

I am storing textbox value in asp cookie.

```
Response.Cookies("Remark") = Uploader.Form("txtremark")
```

But when I see the cookie value then showing me content like : `Test+Remark`

while saveing the value in cookie that (+) sign is coming instead of space.Why this is so?

Please avise me.

Comment: When you read the cookie is the + returned in the resulting string?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are sent via HTTP so are url encoded, the "+" is the url encoding for the space character.

Comment: Ok.Then what I need to do to remove that.Or I want only plain text in cookie...

Please help...